# react native: there is way to handle an input text and save it into the NOTE var of the postData function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

there is way to handle an input text from "Modal2" component and send it into the "NOTE" var of the "postData" function ?
 my mission is when i will press on "Cancel" in "OrderInformationScreen" screen so it will open the "Modal2" and when i will press ok inside this modal so it will send the input text of the "Modal2" into the "NOTE" var that inside the "OrderInformationScreen" screen .

this is the "OrderInformationScreen" screen:

```
export default class OrderInformationScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { state } = props.navigation;
    this.state = {
      title: state.params.data, //navprops.params.data.SHORT_TEXT
      list: [],
      currentIndex: state.params.itemIndex || 0,
      initialIndex: state.params.itemIndex
    };
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(state.params));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const list = InfoStore.getList;
    // console.log("InfoStore getList", list.slice(), this.state.currentIndex);
    this.setState({ list });
  }

  postData = key => {
    const { list, currentIndex } = this.state;
    const ACTOR_ID = list[currentIndex]["ACTOR_ID"];
    const WORK_ITEM_ID = list[currentIndex]["WI_ID"].toString();
    // console.log("ACTOR_ID", currentIndex, ACTOR_ID, WORK_ITEM_ID);
    var REPORT_KEY = key == "Cancel" ? "002" : "001"; //לשתול כסטרינג 001 לאישור ו 002 לדחיה - לבצע עם תנאי
    var NOTE = key == "Cancel" ? this.state.cancelInput : "";
    const pre =
      "https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/OrderApprove/OrderApp_Save_Approvement/ACTOR_ID%2C%20REPORT_KEY%2C%20WORK_ITEM_ID%2C%20NOTE?";
    let params =
      "ACTOR_ID=" +
      ACTOR_ID +
      "&REPORT_KEY=" +
      REPORT_KEY +
      "&WORK_ITEM_ID=" +
      WORK_ITEM_ID +
      "&NOTE=" +
      NOTE;
    const url = pre + params;
    // console.log("THE URL IS>>>>>>>>>", params);
    const axios = require("axios");
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
    //   console.log("roei response======>>>>", response);
      const newList = list.slice();
      newList.splice(currentIndex, 1);

      InfoStore.setList(newList);
    //   console.log("newList", newList);
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
    });
  };

  onSwiperIndexChanged = index => {
    // console.log("onSwiperIndex", index);
    this.setState({ currentIndex: index });
  };

  render() {
    // console.log("render this.state.currentIndex", this.state.currentIndex);
    return (
      <>
        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: "flex-start",
            justifyContent: "center",
            borderColor: "blue",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-evenly"
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.postData("Cancel")}
            disabled={this.state.list.length == 0}
          >
            <Avatar
              size="large"
              containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
              activeOpacity={0.2}
              rounded
              source={require("../assets/down.png")}
              style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
              // onPress={() => console.log("cancel!")}
            />
            <View>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, fontWeight: "bold", color: "red" }}>
                Cancel
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.postData("Confirm")}
            disabled={this.state.list.length == 0}
          >
            <Avatar
              size="large"
              activeOpacity={0.1}
              rounded
              source={require("../assets/up.png")}
              style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
              // onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
            />
            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  color: "green",
                  marginHorizontal: 6
                }}
              >
                Cnfirm
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {this.state.list.length > 0 && (
          <Swiper
            style={styles.wrapper}
            showsButtons={false}
            onIndexChanged={this.onSwiperIndexChanged}
            index={this.state.list.length - this.state.initialIndex - 1}
          >
            {this.state.list.map((item, index) => (
              <InfoTable key={index} headerInfo={item}></InfoTable>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

this is the Modal2:

```
export default class Modal2 extends Component {
  state = {
    placeName: "",
    visibleModal: 3,
  };

  placeNameChangedHandler = val => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: val
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modal> 
        <LinearGradient
              colors={['#43D4FF', 'white']}
              style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
          <View style={styles.modalContent}>
          <Text>reson</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={{width: 300,height:100}}
          placeholder="write here"
          value={this.state.placeName}
          onChangeText={this.placeNameChangedHandler}
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row" ,marginLeft: 20, justifyContent: 'space-evenly',marginBottom:20}}>
    <Button
          title="ok"
          onPress={() => Alert('ok Button pressed')}
        />
    <Button
          title="cancel"
          onPress={() => Alert('not ok Button pressed')}
        />
</View>
         </LinearGradient>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain yourself better? What are you trying to accomplish? Where is the postData function defined?

Comment: i edit my code for you, my mission is when i will press on "Cancel" in "OrderInformationScreen" screen  so it will open the "Modal2" and when i will press ok inside this modal so it will send the input text of the "Modal2" into the "NOTE" var that inside the "OrderInformationScreen" screen

Comment: It's not clear from your code **How** you open `Modal2` but you can define Modal2 to receive (as prop) a function - `onCancel` and it will call it onPress of the `cancel` button with `placeNameChangedHandler` (from the state).

Comment: can you show me please how to do it in my code ?